# Reverting a commit that is a duplicate of another commit from a different pull request

Tags: git, github, merge

Thanks for having me on StackOverflow.

Ok, so I did some work on a branch, committed my code and issued a pull request. Later that day I created a new branch, but I made a mistake, I created the branch from my previous branch instead of master. So my new branch had the commit from the old one. Without realizing what I've done, I proceeded to code, committed my code and issued a pull request. After realizing my mistake, I went into the second branch and reverted the commit that came from the first branch.

Now my question is: If QA merges branch 1, then branch 2, will the code from branch 1 be destroyed, or the pull request for branch 2 will completely ignore the commit I was telling you about earlier and everything will be fine?

Comment: Everything will not be fine, that commit will be reverted. You should rebase second branch on top of master to prevent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than reverting the commit on your second branch, consider rebasing to remove it from history.  That way you won't have to wonder what will happen. :)

$ git rebase --onto master first-pr-branch

That tells git that you *want* to be based on master, but you're *currently* based on your first PR branch.  That will splice the revisions from your first PR branch out of your history.  You'll need to force push after this, since you're rewriting history, but then you'll have a clean change-set on top of master.

Comment: Thank you. A git rebase --interactive HEAD~4 saved me, dropped the commits that leaked and now everything is fine